# .htaccess redirect link with less then 4 slashes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have no problem wiht regex yet I don't know how to write .htaccess rules, could I get how to redirect pages on given rules:

```
OK  /page/product/type/id
301 /page/product/type         => /otherPage/product/type
301 /page/product              => /otherPage/product
301 /page                      => /otherPage
301 /otherPage/product/type/id => /page/product/type/id
```

Comment: Is `page` a fixed string or a dynamic one?

Comment: @anubhava `/page` and `/otherPage` are fixed, rest goes dynamicly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+/[^/]+/?)$ /otherPage/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+/?)$ /otherPage/$1 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^page/?$ /otherPage [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^otherPage/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/?)$ /page/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: How to make 4th line `product` dynamic?

Comment: well it's not. For ex. rule 1. `http://www.example.com/page/product/type` is not redirecting anywhere

Comment: Maybe I need `RewriteCond` or put something before `^`?

Comment: Make sure these rules are placed just below `RewriteEngine` line. As per these rules `http://www.example.com/page/product/type` will be redirected to `http://www.example.com/otherPage/product/type`